# pythons PySerial : multiple scripts reading the same serial

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I am using PYSerial to read a Arduino which outputting data through serial to a Raspberry PI.  On the PI, I'm running Python script that reads the data using pyserial. I want to run another python scripts that also reads the the same data on the same serial.  Would they interfere with each other?  I've tested and both scripts seam to read data and it does not crash or lock the port but wondered if problems would occurs?  Both scripts perform different functions and I want to keep them separate.  Both scripts start with the following code and then do something different when it gets to ##do something##

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 115200) # just change the port number to the appropriate
while True :
    line = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").rstrip()
    ##do something##
```

Comment: Python allows threading. You could run the main thread to read the serial and then fork your 2 python scripts with the data read from serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two scripts read exactly the same data on the serial port, then the second one will have nothing to read, because after reading a byte, it is removed from the RX buffer.

Comment: Brill Thanks for clearing that up.  ah, didnt realise, Is it possible to miss any serial data the Arduino is sending to the PI if my loop isn't quick enough to read the incoming data?   or will it eventually report a error if the buffer gets too big?

Comment: I don't know, maybe readline will raise an IOError exception, in fact the loss of data is probable, but I have never been confronted to this case 
,the best is to test with a loop between Rx and Tx        https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.SerialException